# Multiple maven repositories in Gradle

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I have the following build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/fyber/maven"
        }

        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/supersonic/android-sdk"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.19.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
// Ads
      compile 'com.supersonic.sdk:mediationsdk:6.1.0@jar'
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Error:(88, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.supersonic.sdk:mediationsdk:6.2.0

I've checked that library exists in the repository. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You added those repositories to the `buildscript` list of `repositories`. Hence, those repositories are only used for the `dependencies` listed in `buildscript`.

You need a `repositories` closure *outside* of `buildscript`, listing the repositories where your top-level `dependencies` reside. So, probably what you want is something like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/fyber/maven"
        }   
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.19.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/supersonic/android-sdk"
        }
}

dependencies {
// Ads
      compile 'com.supersonic.sdk:mediationsdk:6.1.0@jar'
}
```